# How to finish this minmax algorithm on connect4

Tags: minimax

i made a minmax algorithm for the connect4 game that is quite unsteady. 
in the first moves, it can easili fight against the user and predict when he can win.
It starts to stumble after some exchanges, where it can't value when it can win directly or it also do moves that help the player to win, i made a pic to show what it's like [AI wrong move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzNzi.png)

i saw quite much docs about the minmax algorithme and don't understand what to do. Thank for any help ! :)

Simon

```
     * Find the best move to do
     * @param game game table
     * @param depth depth to be explored by the algorithm
     * @param turnsLeft number of turns before a drow
     * @param maximizingPlayer true if it's AI's turn
     * @return the column of the best move and its value
     */
    private static minimaxResult miniMax(Puissance4Struct game, int depth, int turnsLeft, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
        minimaxResult minimaxResult = new minimaxResult();

        if (game.verifWinner()) {
            //game.afficherPuissance4();
            if (game.IATurn()) {
                //System.out.println("Je vois une victoire pour l'ordinateur");
                minimaxResult.setValue(100000);
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Je vois une victoire pour le joueur");
                minimaxResult.setValue(-100000);
            }
            return minimaxResult;

        }

        if (depth == 0 || turnsLeft == 0) {

            minimaxResult.setValue(game.tableEvaluation());
            return minimaxResult;
        }


        if (maximizingPlayer) {

            int maxValue = -10000;
            int maxColon = 0;
            minimaxResult.setValue(maxValue);

            for (int col = 0; col < game.getWidthTable(); col++) {
                if (game.findIndex(col)) {
                    game.setToken(Puissance4Struct.getAIToken());
                    game.putToken();

                    minimaxResult = miniMax(game, depth-1, turnsLeft-1, false);

                    game.eraseTokenColon(col);

                    if (maxValue < minimaxResult.getValue()) {
                        maxValue = minimaxResult.getValue();
                        maxColon = col;
                    }
                }
            }
            minimaxResult.setColonne(maxColon);
            minimaxResult.setValue(maxValue);

        } else {
            int minValue = 100000;
            int minColonne = 0;
            minimaxResult.setValue(minValue);

            for (int col = 0; col < game.getWidthTable(); col++) {

                if (game.findIndex(col)) {
                    game.setToken(Puissance4Struct.getPlayerToken());
                    game.putToken();

                    minimaxResult = miniMax(game, depth-1, turnsLeft-1, true);

                    game.eraseTokenColon(col);

                    if (minValue > minimaxResult.getValue()) {
                        minValue = minimaxResult.getValue();
                        minColonne = col;
                    }
                }
            }
            minimaxResult.setColonne(minColonne);
            minimaxResult.setValue(minValue);
            game.eraseToken();
        }
        game.changeToken();
        return minimaxResult;
    }
```

if any need, here is the game class :

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Puissance4Struct game = new Puissance4Struct();
        minimaxResult minimaxResult;
        int input;
        int numberMovesPlayed = 0;
        int maximumMoves =  game.getNombreCases();
        boolean winner = false;
        boolean AITurn = false;

       System.out.println("Do you want to play against an AI ? \n1: yes | 2: no");
        input = (int) Verif.Input(1, 2);

        if (input == 1) { // JCAI
            // Initialise the static token reference for player and AI
            Puissance4Struct.setJetonJoueur(game.getToken());
            game.changeToken();
            Puissance4Struct.setJetonAI(game.getToken());


            while (!winner && numberMovesPlayed < maximumMoves) {
                if (AITurn) {
                    game.setToken(Puissance4Struct.getAIToken());

                    minimaxResult = miniMax(game, 4, maximumMoves - numberMovesPlayed,  true);

                    game.setToken(Puissance4Struct.getAIToken());
                    game.findIndex(minimaxResult.getColonne());
                    game.putToken();
                    ++numberMovesPlayed;

                    if (numberMovesPlayed >= 7) {
                        winner = game.verifWinner();
                    }
                    AITurn = false;

                } else {
                    game.setToken(Puissance4Struct.getPlayerToken());
                    player(game);

                    game.putToken();
                    numberMovesPlayed++;

                    if (numberMovesPlayed >= 7) {
                        winner = game.verifWinner();
                    }
                    AITurn = true;
                }
            }
            game.printConnect4();

        } else { // JCJ

            while (!winner && numberMovesPlayed < maximumMoves) {
                player(game);

                numberMovesPlayed++;
                game.putToken();

                if (numberMovesPlayed >= 7) {
                    winner = game.verifWinner();
                }

                System.out.println();
                game.printConnect4();

            }

        }
        if (winner) {
            System.out.println("\nBravo au joueur " + game.getToken() + " pour avoir gagné en " + numberMovesPlayed + " tours !");
        } else {
            System.out.println("c'est un match nul. Quelle intensité !");
        }

    }
```

and the game board class :

```
package puissance4;


class Puissance4Struct {
    private char [][] tableau = new char[7][7];
    private int[] indice = new int[2];
    private char jeton;
    private static char jetonAI;
    private static char jetonJoueur;

    Puissance4Struct() {
        jeton = 'X';
        initialisationTableau();
    }

    static char getPlayerToken() {
        return jetonJoueur;
    }

    static void setJetonJoueur(char jetonJoueur) {
        if (jetonJoueur == 'O' || jetonJoueur == 'X') {
            Puissance4Struct.jetonJoueur = jetonJoueur;
        }
    }

    int getNombreCases() {
        return tableau.length * tableau[0].length;
    }

    int getWidthTable() {
        return tableau[0].length;
    }

    /**
     * Place l'indice sur la première ligne possible d'une colonne choisie. Renvoie faux s'il n'y a aps de colonne possible.
     * @param colonne l'indice de la colonne.
     * @return <code>false</code> s'il n'y a pas de colonne possible.
     */
    boolean findIndex(int colonne) {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < tableau.length && tableau[i][colonne] == ' ') {
            i++;
        }

        if (i != 0) {
            indice[0] = i - 1;
            indice[1] = colonne;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Attribue des valeur à la variable indice
     * @param ligne ligne du puissance4
     * @param colonne colonne du puisance 4
     */
    private void setIndice(int ligne, int colonne) {
        indice[0] = ligne;
        indice[1] = colonne;
    }

    /**
     * Copie de setIndice, mais ne modifie pas la variable indice de l'objet
     * @param colonne l'indice de la colonne
     * @return retourne le nombre de ligne de la colonne passée en argument. (est-il nécessaire de retourner une valeur?
     * ('void' est peut-être plus approprié)
     */
    private int getIndiceLigne(int colonne) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < tableau.length - 1 && tableau[i][colonne] == ' ') {
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }


    char getToken() {
        return jeton;
    }

    void setToken(char jeton) {
        if (jeton == 'X' || jeton == 'O')
            this.jeton = jeton;
    }


    void changeToken() {
        if (jeton == 'O')
            jeton = 'X';
        else {
            jeton = 'O';
        }
    }


    private void initialisationTableau() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableau.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tableau[0].length; j++) {
                tableau[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }


    void printConnect4() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableau[0].length; i++) // Affiche les nombres au dessus des colonnes
            if (i < 10)
                System.out.print("   "+ (i+1));
            else
                System.out.print("  "+ (i+1));
        System.out.println();

        for (char[] chars : tableau) { // Affichage du puissance 4
            for (int j = 0; j < tableau[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(" | " + chars[j]);
            }
            System.out.println(" |");
            System.out.print(" ");

            for (int k = 0; k < tableau[0].length; k++)
                System.out.print("----");

            System.out.println("-");
        }

    }

    void putToken() {
        tableau[indice[0]][indice[1]] = jeton;
    }


    /**
     * Procède aux vérifications permettant de savoir si le joueur a gagné.
     * @return <code>true</code> si le joueur a gagné.
     */
    boolean verifWinner() {
        // Le vectorValeur faisant à  chaque fois la vérification du vecteur opposé,
        // il n'est pas nécéssaire de mettre les 8 directions.

        for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++) {
            if (vectorValeur( k, -1) >= 4)
                return true;
        }

        return vectorValeur(1, 0) >= 4;
    }

    /**
     * Donne le nombre de même jetons sur un sens de l'indice
     * @param vectorI direction verticale du vecteur donné
     * @param vectorJ direction horizontale du vecteur donné
     * @return le nombre de même jeton dans le sens donné
     */
    private int vectorValeur(int vectorI, int vectorJ) {
        int recurrence = 0;
        int i = indice[0];
        int j = indice[1];
        int edgeI = calculEdgePoint(vectorI, 'i'), edgeJ = calculEdgePoint(vectorJ, 'j');

        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            do {
                i += vectorI;
                j += vectorJ;
                recurrence++;
            } while (i != edgeI && j != edgeJ && tableau[i][j] == jeton);

            if (k == 0) {
                i = indice[0];
                j = indice[1];
                vectorI = -vectorI; // Continue à  chercher dans la direction opposée, c'est la raison pour le For avec k
                vectorJ = -vectorJ;
                edgeI = calculEdgePoint(vectorI, 'i');
                edgeJ = calculEdgePoint(vectorJ, 'j');
            }

        }
        recurrence -= 1;

        return recurrence;
    }

    /**
     * @param vectorPoint donne la case de l'indice
     * @param indice définit si c'est un point i ou j
     * @return le point prime que i ou j ne devra pas dépasser
     */
    private int calculEdgePoint(int vectorPoint, char indice) { // Donne la valeur pour i ou j à ne pas dépasser
        if (vectorPoint == -1 || vectorPoint == 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (indice == 'i') {
            return tableau.length;
        } else {
            return tableau[0].length;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Donne la valeur de la combinaison testée.
     * @return la valeur de la combinaison.
     */
    private int verifTailleCombinaison() {
        int valCombinaisons = 0;

        for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k = k + 2) {
            valCombinaisons += vectorValeur(k, -1);
        }

        valCombinaisons += vectorValeur(1, 0);

        return valCombinaisons;
    }

    /**
     * Indique si le tour actuel est celui de l'IA
     * @return <code>true</code> si le jeton utilisé correspond à celui de l'IA
     */
    boolean IATurn() {
        return getToken() == getAIToken();
    }

    /**
     * Donne une évaluation du tableau actuelle.
     * Elle est négative ou positive si le tableau est favorable pour l'humain ou l'IA respectivement
     * @return l'évaluation du tableau.
     */
    int tableEvaluation() {
        int baseI = indice[0], baseJ = indice[1];
        int score = 0;

        for (int ligne = 0; ligne < tableau.length; ligne++) {
            for (int colonne = 0; colonne < tableau[0].length; colonne++) {
                if (findIndex(colonne)) {
                    putToken();
                    score += verifTailleCombinaison();
                    eraseTokenColon(colonne);
                }
            }
        }

        changeToken();

        for (int col = 0; col < tableau.length; col++) {
            if (findIndex(col)) {
                putToken();
                score -= verifTailleCombinaison();
                eraseTokenColon(col);
            }
        }

        changeToken();

        setIndice(baseI, baseJ);

        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Efface le jeton de la colonne choisie
     * @param colonne la colonne choisie
     */
    void eraseTokenColon(int colonne) {
        int ligne = getIndiceLigne(colonne);
        tableau[ligne][colonne] = ' ';
    }


    /**
     * Efface le jeton actuellement sélectionné par l'indice
     */
    void eraseToken() {
        tableau[indice[0]][indice[1]] = ' ';
    }

    static char getAIToken() {
        return jetonAI;
    }

    static void setJetonAI(char jetonAI) {
        if (jetonAI == 'X' || jetonAI == 'O') {
            Puissance4Struct.jetonAI = jetonAI;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sooo... i finally got the solution...
I made it to return the value(10000) + depth if it's maxplayer or - depth if it's minplayer

Comment: I somehow managed it. I give here he solution if it can help someone.
The problem was the recursive mingle the tokens of player and AI.
I can't put all the code so here is the git link : https://github.com/Fendrul/Puissance4.git